# How to mark Apple method as unavailable?

Tags: swift, deprecation-warning

I have a Swift project and I want to mark an Apple method as unavailable for my project. How can I do this?

Comment: While there are tricks to sort-of do this (such as marking the method deprecated via an extension using `@available`), I'm not aware of any way that isn't dangerous (overriding methods with an extension is not defined behavior, and could cause runtime problems). What method are you trying to ban, and why? I'd be tempted to write a custom swiftlint rule or similar approach.

Comment: Yeah I'll probably make a lint rule for it, ty

Answer (score -3):

Yes. you may consider maybe just for your own method:

```
   “@available(*, unavailable, renamed: "MyRenamedProtocol")”

See the  “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.1).” Apple Books.
```

If you don't need an Apple method, just don't import it.

Comment: But that's just for my own methods

Comment: Yes you can use this for your own method. You don’t need to use rename part, just the first argument